# Sidebar doesn't have the full height of the webpage

Tags: html, css

I have problem that my sidebar doesn't have the full height of the webpage. Trying to fix this problem for hours but can't... Can someone tell me how to fix that?

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar-inverse {
     background-color: #455a64;
     color: #f7f6f6;
     vertical-align: middle;
     height: 50px;
     line-height: 50px;
     font-size: 16px;
    }

    nav .col-sm-2 a {
     color: #f7f6f6;
     margin-left: 40%;
    }

    hr {
     border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    }

    nav .col-sm-2 a:hover {
     color: #ebebeb;
     text-decoration: none;
    }

.container-fluid .row .col-sm-2 {
 margin-top: -30px;
 background-color: #455a64;
 height: 100%;
}

.navbar {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 border-bottom: 0;
}

.container-fluid .row .col-sm-2 a {
 color: #ebebeb;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.container-fluid .row .col-sm-2 a:hover {
 color: #26c6da;
 text-decoration: none;
}

    .active {
     color: #26c6da!important;
     text-decoration: none;
    }

    .glyphicon {
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     padding-right: 15px;
    }

    .glyphicon-menu-right {
     float: right;
    }

    .glyphicon-menu-left {
     float: right;
    }


    #panel {
     margin-top: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Creator CRM</title>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="../css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aclonica" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top"></nav>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <hr>
              <a href="../index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Homepage <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span></a><br>
              <a class="active" href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Modules <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span></a><br>
              <span class="title">Installed modules<hr></span>
              <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Users management <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span></a><br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <div id="panel">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">Your current plan: <strong>Free</strong> <button class="btn btn-blue">Upgrade your plan to install more modules!</button></div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
 L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>L<br>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Added my code above. For bigger screens there is chance that you can't see that bug. So I leave a picture here too:[image: Bug with height]

Thanks in advance for help!:)

P.S Open in full page to better see problem, because it's not implemented to smaller devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` on the parent, and remove the `height` attribute from the sidebar because the height will "stretch" by default to match the height of the parent.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #455a64;
  color: #f7f6f6;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

nav .col-sm-2 a {
  color: #f7f6f6;
  margin-left: 40%;
}

hr {
  border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

nav .col-sm-2 a:hover {
  color: #ebebeb;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container-fluid .row .col-sm-2 {
  margin-top: -30px;
  background-color: #455a64;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.container-fluid .row .col-sm-2 a {
  color: #ebebeb;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container-fluid .row .col-sm-2 a:hover {
  color: #26c6da;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
  color: #26c6da!important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.glyphicon {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.glyphicon-menu-right {
  float: right;
}

.glyphicon-menu-left {
  float: right;
}

#panel {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Creator CRM</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aclonica" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top"></nav>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <hr>
        <a href="../index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Homepage <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span></a><br>
        <a class="active" href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Modules <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left"></span></a><br>
        <span class="title">Installed modules<hr></span>
        <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Users management <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right"></span></a><br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div id="panel">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Your current plan: <strong>Free</strong> <button class="btn btn-blue">Upgrade your plan to install more modules!</button></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
             <div style="height: 200vh"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ah... I didn't saw that if there is too little content in the panel then sidebar background doesn't have full height of web page.. :/ (Try to change panel body div height to 20vh)